# Having trouble with Terms of Service and Mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, mongoid

Hey I have a simple rails app setup with a devise model named worker and a regular model named user.

```
Worker:
  has_one :user, as: :account, autobuild: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user

User:
  belongs_to :account, polymorphic: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :account
```

On my user model I have a boolean field for :tos with a default to :false. When my user creates a new devise account on the sign_up page I want to take in the tos checkbox input as worker[user_attributes][tos] and on the user model validate the acceptance and store the value as true on the model for the :tos field.

My checkbox:

```
%input{ name: 'worker[user_attributes][tos]', type: 'checkbox', value: '1' }
```

My user validation:

```
validates_acceptance_of :tos, allow_nil: false, on: :create
```

For some reason tho it doesn't seem that the validation works, is there any configuration I have to make to devise to make this happen? If i take out the validation the account is just created and tos remains false in the database and if I add the validation and check the box it says validation failed.

Comment: Please share the server log(with `params` hash) generated upon submitting the form.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of saving the tos for each user,remove it from your migration then do the following

```
attr_reader :tos
validates_acceptance_of :tos
```